Problems getting a 310 V Airco motor driver running using a microprocessor
The driver has two 5-pin connectors for the motor, a potentiometer to control the speed of one motor and a micro processor connect PWM to control the second motor (the outside unit and the inside unit.)
When I connect a motor to connector one, I can control the speed of that motor using the potentiometer.
When I try to measure the signals on the connector pins using my scope I get a short circuit. The documentation is very restricted. The only statement I can find about the microprocessor is that it needs a common ground. It seems that I not able to measure the signals.
.
I did connect it to an ESP32 and a test program that generate a PWM signal but the motor did not move. I powered the ESP32 using the 15V power line and a step-down converter. In this way it has a common ground. I tried to search on Youtube for this driver but did not find an example of this motor driver and and microprocessor.
I need some help to go forward. How I can measure the signals without a short circuit?

I'm assuming English is not your first language. I attempted to improve your question but I am not sure what you mean in a few places. Please check whether the meaning is still correct.

Thanks for improving the text

Youtube is for entertainment, not technical information.

DANGER
This circuit board can kill you.
Do not touch any part of the board when it is plugged in.  The 310V supply is not isolated, and I doubt that the 15V supply is isolated.  If you clip the ground lead of your oscilloscope to any part of the board, you will cause a short circuit.
The only part that is isolated is the lower right corner where the PWM signal comes in:

The two white things there are optocouplers.
The ground connection on the PWM connector is not connected to the ground of the 15V supply.  If you connect the PWM ground to the other ground, then your microprocessor will be floating at 310VDC - that can kill you if you touch the microprocessor.
If you don't connect the PWM ground to the other ground, but you do use the 15V power supply then the microprocessor will still be floating at 310V (it can still kill you,) but the microprocessor will not run (no ground.)

Use a separate, isolated power supply for the microprocessor.
Do NOT connect the PWM ground to the motor ground.
Do NOT touch any part of the board.  It is floating at line voltage or 310VDC - it will kill you.
Do NOT touch any part of the board with the ground clip of your oscilloscope - it will cause a short circuit which may damage the scope, the board, or both.
That circuit board MUST be enclosed in an insulated housing (plastic) or in a grounded metal housing (connected to protective earth.)
You MUST connect the PWM ground to the microprocessor.
You MUST connect a 5V power supply to the PWM section of the board.  That's most likely the "PG" pin of the PWM connector.  I'd get a 5V supply to power the PWM section, then drop the 5V to 3.3V to power the microcontroller.  You may need to translate the PWM signal from the microcontroller from 3.3V to 5V.

It is likely that your microprocessor was not getting power if you connected to it to the 15V line and the PWM ground.

If you must make measurements, then you must use an isolation transformer.
Plug the circuit board in to the isolation transformer, then you can clip your oscilloscope ground lead to the ground on the PCB.  You will need an isolation transformer with a power rating high enough to supply the board and the motor.
Keep in mind that the board will still be at line voltage.  If you touch the board and the board ground at the same time, you can still be zapped (and killed.)

1-When I study the connections for the micro processor I can see I connection between the PG pin and one of the optocouplers. I can also see an connection between the PWM pin to the other optocoupler. The two groundpins are connected. Is it posible that this circuit is powered by the signal lines of the microprocessor. Becouse I think that the PG pin is the feedback signal of the motor.
2-Do I need an isolated power supply for the micro prosesor?  Becouse it is isolated from the other parts of the board I think it will do no harm. Thanks

Thanks a lot for your answer. I have it working using the ESP32 at 3,3V. I do not need a extra power supply for the optocoupler it is powerd by the signal line. I have it working now at 1000Hz signal and I power the ESP32 using a standard USB power supply. To measur the signals of the board, I orded a 30W isolated transformer 220V to 220V for my OWON SDS1102 ociloscoop.
Thanks a lot for your verry complete answer, it contained al the info I need to proceed
John
